# Getting reference to dependent in service with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac

I need this IService to be reusable. Whenever IService is injected into a constructor, I need Service.Dependent to reference the type of the injected class.

```
builder.Register<Service>(c =>
        {
            var a = new Service();
            a.Dependent = c.Resolve<CallingType??>(TypedParameter.From(a));
            return a;
        }).As<IService>();

interface IService {}

class Service : IService {
    BaseClass Dependent {get; set;}
}


class SomeClass : BaseClass {
    SomeClass(IService service) {
        service.Dependent //This should be type BaseClass of SomeClass
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofac supports [open generic registration](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html?#open-generic-components) and [circular dependencies](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html#constructor-property-dependencies).
So it can be done like:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof (Service<>))
    .As(typeof (IService<>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope()
    .PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringOptions.AllowCircularDependencies);
builder.RegisterType<SomeClass>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And `container.Resolve<IService<SomeClass>>()` will return you service with injected instance of `SomeClass` which will receive this `Service` instance recursively.

Seems like there is no option for extracting callee type during registration.
For your updated example custom [Registration Source](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html#implementing-a-registration-source) may be helpful.
It's a "generic" registration for inherited from `BaseType` types.
But it looks like overengineering.

> ```
> public class HandlerRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
> {
>   public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
>     Service service,
>     Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
>   {
>     var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
>     if(swt == null || !typeof(BaseClass).IsAssignableFrom(swt.ServiceType))
>     {
>       // It's not a request for the BaseClass type, so skip it.
>       return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();
>     }        
>     var registration = new ComponentRegistration(
>       Guid.NewGuid(),
>       new DelegateActivator(swt.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
>         {
>           var myService = c.Resolve<IService>();
>           ...
>         }
>         ...
>   }
>   ...
> }
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in my updated example. Does autofac have a way to use reflection at registration to reference the calling type?